# I am struggling with part v

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am currently taking a linear algebra class in university. For part v wouldn't the matrix D just be the matrix C with the row r appended to it?

Comment: Please set a meaningful title. We are all struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Since $A$ and $B$ are $3 \times 5$ matrices, in order for $CA = B$, we need $C$ to be a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Since $A'$ and $B'$ are $4 \times 5$ matrices, in order for $DA' = B'$, we need $D$ to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

You do have the right intuition that you can use the matrix $C$ you found to fill most of the entries of the matrix $D$. Specifically, the top-left $3 \times 3$ block of the $4 \times 4$ matrix $D$ will be $C$. Can you figure out what the remaining entries are?

Answer (score 0):

Let C be the top 3 by 3 matrix D. You can then set the first three numbers of the last column to 0 and $d_{4,4}=1$. Then you see that this means the last row of $B'$ is equal to the last row of $A'$ and the first three rows of $B'$ are equal to the first three rows of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is going to be $C$ with an extra row and an extra column.  All the extra entries will be zero, except for $d_{44}=1$.

That is, the extra row and column are $(0,0,0,1)$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$, respectively.

The reason being that the $ij$-th entry of $B'$ is the $i$-th row of $D$ dotted with the $j$-th column of $A'$.